# Piston Compressed Pneumatic Cannon

Tags: pressure, compressed-air, pneumatic

During an discussion with friends regarding pneumatic cannons, I came up with this gem :). Piston power pneumatic cannon. My friends however, didn't share my excitement regarding this revolution in the potato chucking industry.

The idea is simple: Using the gas laws, we can work out that if the volume of a container is halved, the pressure will double.

- Step 1. The piston will be push as far as possible into the container (this would require some sort of racket system/locking so you don't get a 100+psi punch).
- Step 2. The value is opened to release pressure, and fire the projectile.
- Step 3. The piston is pulled back, opening valves, through which air is drawn.

[image]

The potential issues I see are as follows:

- The strength of the air container
- The force required to push the piston would be equal to the area of the piston times the force of the air. A lot of force.

Am I missing some critical mechanical failure point?
Is this a feasible plan, or is there a reason this is not really done?

Comment: Sounds like any bike pump.

Comment: True. That is basically what I am was thinking. However unlike a bicycle pump, this would release 80-100psi all at once.

Comment: So add a reservoir a non-return valve and a ball valve… basically a compressor with tank.

Comment: you are describing a pump action pellet gun

Answer (score 0):

In this picture [BRANDT 60mm PNEUMATIC MORTAR](http://douglas-self.com/MUSEUM/COMMS/pneuguns/brandt4.jpg) you can see a couple of guys with a hand pump for pressurizing the air tank. (That whole page is worth looking at, as is the whole online ["museum" of retro-tech](http://douglas-self.com/MUSEUM/COMMS/pneuguns/pneuguns.htm))

You write "the valve is opened" as if that is a minor detail :) Actually valve design and control is a critical element of engine design, and was a critical element of steam engine design, so the pneumatic gun designers had a running start.

The second problem I see is that you've got a wide short-throw pump: the force required is proportional to the area of the piston. You'll note that real bicycle pumps are long and narrow.  I don't think you'll be able to get enough air at enough pressure to do more than tumble a potato out.